# How can I create new graphic objects automatically by using Timer in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer, jframe

Hi my program is similar to a tetris game, in the quality that it tries to create new 'shapes' that float upward every few seconds.

My goal is to create alot of new objects that will continue to float upward. 
The only way I got my code to work was pre define a few 'lines' and make them loop back to the bottom of the page after hitting the top. 
But I don't want to do it like this.

My aim is to make a tetris game where an indefinitely amount of terminos will fall from the sky. Perhaps I could pre-define the maximum number of terminos and store them in a data-structure and randomly select from there.. But I am wondering if there is another way.

```
public class Board {

    private int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    private Line line;
    private Timer timer;
    private long second;
    private Line[] lines = { new Line(0, 500, 500, 500),
            new Line(0, 600, 500, 600), new Line(0, 700, 500, 700),
            new Line(0, 800, 500, 800), new Line(0, 900, 500, 900) };
    private Dude dude;

    public Board() {
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        dude = new Dude(230, 10);
        line = new Line(0, 400, 500, 400);
        final JPanel board = new MyBoard();
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(board);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        second = 1;
        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                second++;
                System.out.println(second);
                line.moveD();
                frame.repaint();
                if (line.isTop()) {
                    line.setXY(0, 400, 500, 400);

                }

                // board.repaint();
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    if (lines[i].isTop()) {
                        lines[i].setXY(0, 500, 500, 500);
                    }
                    lines[i].moveD();
                }
                int i = 0;
                dude.twitch();
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    System.out.println("r");
                    dude.moveR();
                    frame.repaint();
                    // Right arrow key code
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    System.out.println("l");
                    dude.moveL();
                    frame.repaint();
                    // Left arrow key code
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    System.out.println("u");
                    dude.moveU();
                    frame.repaint();
                    // Up arrow key code
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    // Down arrow key code
                    System.out.println("d");
                    dude.moveD();
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

        });
    }

    class MyBoard extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            dude.draw(g);
            line.draw(g);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

             * for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){ lines[i].draw(g); }


            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillOval(dude.getX(), dude.getY(), 10, 10);

        }

    }
}
```

---

```
package Shapes;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Line {
    private int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    public Line(int initx1, int inity1, int initx2, int inity2) {
        x1 = initx1;
        y1 = inity1;
        x2 = initx2;
        y2 = inity2;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        int xone = x1;
        int xtwo = x2;
        int yone = y1;
        int ytwo = y2;
        g.drawLine(xone, yone, xtwo, ytwo);

    }

    public boolean isTop() {
        return y1 == 0;
    }

    public void setXY(int initx1, int inity1, int initx2, int inity2) {
        x1 = initx1;
        y1 = inity1;
        x2 = initx2;
        y2 = inity2;
    }

    public void moveD() {
        if (y1 != -10) {
            y1 += -10;
            y2 += -10;
        }
    }

}
```

Essentially, I want to produce what this website does-alot of graphical objects.
http://mangaarun.blogspot.com/2011/12/creating-paint-brush-application-in.html
I ommited what 'Dude' was, since it's just a drawing of a person.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to have random shapes created at a specified interval.
Logically I would approach it like this.

You can use a timer: each time it fires, have it create a new shape and add it to the list of shapes. So in the actionPerformed, just put (with an arrayList for example)

```
linesList.add(new Line(random x/y));
```

If you have a fixed number of dimensions for your shapes, store those separately and draw one at random for every new shape.

Loop through the list to move all visible elements (like you already do). If an element has passed the screen or frame border, delete it from the list. So you won't have to 'reset' used shapes to be shown again.

Because you'll be adding and deleting shapes, the list size will be balanced, but will also depend on how fast they'll be moving (and thus deleted) and how fast the creation timer is set.
You might want to try an ArrayList instead of an array.